# Формирование по дате в jquery или в javascript

Tags: jquery, javascript

Помогите пожалуйста! Нужно в колонке фотографий сделать так что бы фотографии сортировались автоматом! Чтобы Новое фото занимала первые позиции. Может как то использовать функцию before()?

```
<ul id="main_menu">
    <li><a href="/press/news/">Новости</a>
                        </li>
    <li><a href="/press/photo/">Фотогалерея</a>
    <ul>
           <li><a onclick="javascript: document.location.href='/press/photo/01102013---mezhdunarodnyiy-den/52'" style="cursor: pointer;">01.10.2013 </a></li>
        <li><a onclick="javascript: document.location.href='/press/photo'" style="cursor: pointer;">13.09.2013 -</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="javascript: document.location.href='/press/photo/14112013---/57'" style="cursor: pointer;">14.11.2013 - </a></li>
        <li><a onclick="javascript: document.location.href='/press/photo/14122013---'" style="cursor: pointer;">14.12.2013 - </a></li>
        <li><a onclick="javascript: document.location.href='/press/photo/22112013---/54'" style="cursor: pointer;">22.11.2013 - </a></li>
        <li><a onclick="javascript: document.location.href='/press/photo/24012014---/60'" style="cursor: pointer;">24.01.2014 - </a></li>
        <li><a onclick="javascript: document.location.href='/press/photo/26092013---/50'" style="cursor: pointer;">26.09.2013 -</a></li>
<li><a onclick="javascript: document.location.href='/press/photo/28112013-01122013---/58'" style="cursor: pointer;">28.11.2013-01.12.2013 - </a></li>
        <li><a onclick="javascript: document.location.href='/press/photo/30112013---/55'" style="cursor: pointer;">30.11.2013 -</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="javascript: document.location.href='/press/photo/zolotoy-fond/62'" style="cursor: pointer;"></a></li>
        <li><a onclick="javascript: document.location.href='/press/photo/03062013/25'" style="cursor: pointer;">03.06.2013 - </a></li>
        <li><a onclick="javascript: document.location.href='/press/photo/20052013---/7'" style="cursor: pointer;">20.05.2013 - </a></li>
        <li><a onclick="javascript: document.location.href='/press/photo/_609bdf295f5838a/8'" style="cursor: pointer;">22.02.2013 - </a></li>
        <li><a onclick="javascript: document.location.href='/press/photo/28122012---/9'" style="cursor: pointer;">12.28.2012 - </a></li>
        <li><a onclick="javascript: document.location.href='/press/photo/01112012---/32'" style="cursor: pointer;">01.11.2012 - </a></li>
        <li><a onclick="javascript: document.location.href='/press/photo/05122012---/43'" style="cursor: pointer;">05.12.2012 - </a></li>
        <li><a onclick="javascript: document.location.href='/press/photo/24112012---/44'" style="cursor: pointer;">24.11.2012 -</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="javascript: document.location.href='/press/photo/20112012---/45'" style="cursor: pointer;">20.11.2012 - </a></li>
        <li><a onclick="javascript: document.location.href='/press/photo//46'" style="cursor: pointer;"></a></li>
        <li><a onclick="javascript: document.location.href='/press/photo//47'" style="cursor: pointer;"></a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

Помогите!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Немного подправил HTML (добавил класс и проставил корректные даты). Функция сортировки будет работать только если в начале строки стоит корректная дата (дальше может быть что угодно).

```
var items = $('.items li');

var date_sort_desc = function (li1, li2) {
    var date1 = getDate(li1)
        date2 = getDate(li2);
    if (date1 > date2) return -1;
    if (date1 < date2) return 1;
    return 0;
};

var getDate = function (li){
    var dateStr = li.innerText,
        re = /^(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})/,
        match = dateStr.match(re);

    if (match != null) {
        return new Date(match[0].replace(re, '$3-$2-$1'));
    }
};

items.sort(date_sort_desc);

$('.items').html(items)
```

[Тест на JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/McZ97/)

Comment: Класс! Спасибо тебе!

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста! Что значить этот кусок мат. кода re = /^(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})/,?

Comment: Я так понял это регулярное выражение. Но что значит /^(\d{2}).(\d{2}).(\d{4})/, ?

Comment: И чт означит этот код '$3-$2-$1' ?

Comment: @Arty21, вмешаюсь в ваш диалог, позволите?

Вы правильно написали, это - регулярное выражение. \d означает цифры, {2} - их количество, круглые скобки - команда "запомнить". $1, $2, $3 - используются в подстановке, означают - вставить запомненное №1, 2, 3 соответственно